# About radiation therapy

Tags: radiation, cancer

With radiation therapy, could some of the radiation used cause new mutations in non-cancerous cells that are near the tumour that is being irradiated? If so could these new mutations lead to new cancerous cell colonies (which might later metastasize)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can happen, although the risk is low. The problem is that some tumors need to be irradiated since the cannot be operated (this is true for some brain tumors). Here the radiation therapy is the therapy of choice. The effect of the therapy is that the tumor cells get a high radiation dose which either kills them or drives them into apoptosis.

The problem the irradiation is that you will always affect healthy cells, of which most will die. This causes some of the negative effects of the radiation therapy, but it is also possible that a healthy cell receives a dose which is "only" damaging and causes a secondary tumor. Here a benefit analysis needs to be done to see if the benefit from the therapy is woth taking the risk of acquiring more damages. See the references for some more background.

References:

1. [Long term side effects of brain tumour radiotherapy](http://www.cancerresearchuk.org/about-cancer/type/brain-tumour/treatment/radiotherapy/long-term-side-effects-of-brain-tumour-radiotherapy)
2. [Second Cancers Caused by Cancer Treatment](http://www.cancer.org/cancer/cancercauses/othercarcinogens/medicaltreatments/secondcancerscausedbycancertreatment/second-cancers-caused-by-cancer-treatment-toc)
3. [Therapy-Related Secondary Cancers](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK13999/)

Comment: I thought the apoptosis mechanisms in a cancerous cell have malfunctioned or are damaged ( that's why a cancer cell can't be shut down by its own 'self-destruct' mechanisms) so if a cancer cell is 'killed' by a high dosage of radiation how does this happen?

Comment: DNA double strand breaks, damage to proteins or the cell itself due to the high energy and so on.

Comment: How likely is a high dose of radiation going to cause DNA double strand breaks or damage to proteins or damage to the whole cell and so on regarding any type of cells in the high dosage 'path'? This sounds a lot like some sort of disintegration ray gun you here about in science fiction stories. How long has radiation therapy been used? 50 years?

Comment: Has anybody lived for 10 years after their last 'set' of radiation doses?

Comment: If radiation therapy can lead to new mutations but the risk is low..; how does anyone know if the risk is low as cancerous cells are hard to detect ,probably harder to detect when metastasizing. Even when a new colony of cancerous cells coalesce they.re hard to detect. So how is it determined if the risk is low?

Comment: @201044 It is clearly a trade-off between benefit and harm. Often cancers which are irradiated are the ones, that cannot be removed surgically (or completely). Then the tumor is immediately dangerous for the patient. From the dose the patient gets, you can calculate how likely additional damage is. And then you need to make a decision...

Comment: What kind of radiation is used in radiation therapy?

Comment: Since cancer cells are a lot more unstable than 'regular' cells couldn't a type and duration of radiation be found that would destabilize a cancerous cell and not harm a 'regular' cell?

Comment: A recent news item mentioned women who have had more than the usual amount of some type of scan ( Xray or C.T?) are more likely to develop further cancerous growths. Is this true? Using radiation to kill tumors is sort of like using a small amount of fire to 'get rid of' a big fire.

Comment: Are there ANY other types of radiation or radiant energy that could kill tumors. Like infrared radiation or microwaves?

Comment: @201044 Since the radiation therapy has to do harm in order to damage (to drive it into apoptosis) or kill the cancer cells, it is harmful. And thus it can cause cancer by itself. The question is the benefit of the patient and if it is ok to take this risk. As far as I know no other radiant energy sources are used, as these transport less energy into the tissue.

Comment: I don't think any others are used.

Comment: It should tell you something that they are *not* used, right? General rule for cancer therapy is: Everything what helps, does no harm and makes sense *is* used.

Comment: Radiation therapy has been used for 50 years at least; Marie Curie helped to start the practice. I was wondering if ANYBODY  has worked on the idea of using microwaves or infrared radiation or something else in all those 50 years??

Comment: In the last 50 years is cancer treatment JUST surgery or chemo therapy or radiation therapy and possible slight variations or combinations of these?

Comment: 'Everything that helps, does no harm and makes sense is used..' ; yet radiation therapy can do harm and make a person feel sick ,right? Could narrow beans of intense microwave radiation kill tumors without doing much other damage? Microwave radiation wouldn't cause new tumors..

Comment: @201044 It is always the decision what is more harmful in the short and in the long term. Yes, radiation can be harmful, but cancers pose a much more immediate danger. I think microwave radiation is absorbed by the upper layers of the skin, so it won'T work in the lower parts.

Comment: Well if two narrow beams of microwave radiation that intersected where a tumor was it would be more intense  at the tumor site and have less energy elsewhere so it might not be absorbed by the skin. In a microwave oven the microwaves heat the food from the inside out ,( I don't know if that is because many of the beams of energy intersect at the 'insides' of the food).